# Javascript inheritance with access to *all* methods in 'superclass'?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, smalltalk, super

Trying to understand how inheritance can be done in Javascript, I stumbled across many differerent implementations, including Crockfords, Resigs, `Prototype`, `klass`, and others.

What I missed (I brace myself for the uproar) was the Smalltalkish self/super pair: `self` playing a similar role than `this`, namely representing the current "object", and `super` referring to a superclass-only version of `this`.

[Skip to "]" if you know what `super` does in Smalltalk: Assuming `Subclass` has overriden `method1` defined in `Superclass`, I can still access the superclass implementation using `super.method1()` in `Subclass.method2()`. This will not execute the `Subclass.method1()` code.

```
function Superclass () {
}
Superclass.prototype.method1 = function () {
  return "super";
}

function Subclass () {
}
Subclass.prototype.method1 = function () {
  return "sub";
}
Subclass.prototype.method2 = function () {
  alert (super.method1 ());
}

var o = new Subclass;
o.method2 (); // prints "super"
```

]

Is there any "Javatalk" package out there? So far, I have seen only OO emulations in Javascript which give access to the superclass implementation of the currently defined method (`method2`), not any other (such as `method1`).

Thanks, nobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to implement a `super` feature in JavaScript. For instance:

```
function SuperClass(someValue) {
    this.someValue = someValue;
}

SuperClass.prototype.method1 = function () {
    return this.someValue;
};

function SubClass(someValue) {
    //call the SuperClass constructor
    this.super.constructor.call(this, someValue);
}

//inherit from SuperClass
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

//create the super member that points to the SuperClass prototype
SubClass.prototype.super = SuperClass.prototype;

SubClass.prototype.method2 = function () {
    alert(this.super.method1.call(this));
};

var sub = new SubClass('some value');

sub.method2();
```

EDIT:

Here's an example of an extremely generic `super` method that relies on non-standard features. **I really do not recommend this and it's just there as learning purposes.**

```
Object.prototype.super = function () {
    var superProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)),
        fnName = arguments.callee.caller.name,
        constructorName = this.constructor.name;

    if (superProto == null) throw constructorName + " doesn't have a superclass";
    if (typeof superProto[fnName] !== 'function') {
        throw constructorName + "'s superclass (" 
            + superProto.constructor.name + ") doesn't have a " + fnName + ' function';
    }

    return superProto[arguments.callee.caller.name].apply(
        this, 
        [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    );
};   


function A() {
}

A.prototype.toString = function toString() {
    //call super method Object.prototype.toString
    return this.super();
};

var a = new A();

console.log(a.toString());
```

Comment: One of the Javascript plagues - "there are so many ways" :-)  So now is the time to write my own subclassing function! SO many repetitions of `Superclass` and `Subclass` and `prototype` -- doesn't look DRY at all... Thanks anyway

Comment: @virtualnobi You can definitely make this DRYer especially if you encapsulate the inheritance process within a function. You could always push it the the extreme and have an extremely generic `super` method but I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `super` feature in JavaScript.

When you know the superclass, you can call the super method directly using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

```
Superclass.method1.call(this);
```

If you want to emulate a generic `super` (which I don't advocate), you could use this :

```
function sup(obj, name) {
     var superclass = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
     return superclass[name].apply(obj, [].slice.call(arguments,2));
}
```

that you would use as

```
sup(this, 'method1');
```

instead of your

```
super.method1();
```

And if you have arguments to pass :

```
sup(this, 'method1', 'some', 'args');
```

instead of

```
super.method1('some', 'args');
```

---

Note that this supposes proper prototype inheritance that you set using

```
Subclass.prototype = new Superclass();
```

Comment: Your instead ofs are wrong, it's more instead of `super.method1.call(this);`

Comment: @plalx My "instead of" aren't proper javascript but refer to OP's question.

Comment: It's just that he might think that they are logically equivalent.

Comment: @dystroy I'll try both your approach and the one marked as answer - marked the other simply because it looks nicer in source -- `sup(this, "method")` is ugly, I think. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okey, long story short: [this](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-7-1-oop-general-theory/) is the best JavaScript tutorial I've ever read. So I can recomment it to you. Good luck!

Comment: this definitely looks worthwhile, I've not used seen article citing many different languages. I'll take a look

Comment: I think, you'll like it :) Good luck!